# Save a hash for every classes in an iPhone App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, xcode4

I have to save a token that I receive from an API (HTTP basic authentication). The token will  be transmitted for every request on the application (in every classes). The App receive that token in the first class and should not ask again a new token!

How could I make to save the token???

Class1 : ask a token, use the token during requests
Class2 : use the token during requests

Thanks from an iPhone newbie ;-)

Comment: Please rephrase your question. I can't tell if you're asking how to create a hash for storing something in a dictionary (a complex topic), or a checksum for verifying data sent over the wire, or something else.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a singleton object that is used to store the token in.  Class1 would get the token and would then give this token to the singleton.  The singleton would then hold this token and make it available to all other classes as and when they need it.

Class1:

```
myToken = [self getToken];
[TokenStoringSingleton setToken:myToken];
....
```

Class2 (or any other class that wants to use the token):

```
myToken = [TokenStoringSingleton getToken];
....
```

You could also create a new instance variable in your App Delegate to store it
e.g. 
MyAppDelegate.h

```
NSString *myToken;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *myToken;
```

MyAppDelegate.m

```
@synthesize myToken;
```

Then you could use it from your classes
Class1:

```
myToken = [self getToken];  // This calls a method that gets the token from the server
MyAppDelegate *delegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
delegate.myToken = myToken;
```

Class2:

```
MyAppDelegate *delegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
myToken = delegate.myToken;
```

Comment: It us a good idea to make the singleton receive the token also.

Comment: and the singleton class could make the request itself, no?

Comment: I think that's what WTP meant in his comment.

Comment: @WTP : Ok thanks... I tried to doing it, but I have hundred errors :-(